# What pin is the external interrupt #0 for an arduino micro?

Tags: arduino-micro, mpu6050

I'm putting an MPU6050 on an arduino Micro but the interrupt is different than the arduino uno. The external interrupt #0 pin on an arduino uno is pin 2 but its not pin 2 on an arduino micro. So I'm trying to figure out what pin it is on an arduino micro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ATmega32U4 pin mapping](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping32u4) says 3.

Comment: But pin 3 is the SCL. I'm using that pin to communicate an nrf24l01

Comment: Well, you have the mapping now. Pick something.